# flutter navigator links / routes doesn't work from external

Tags: flutter, browser, hyperlink, flutter-web, navigator

I'm building a webapp with flutter and Navigator 2.0.
The in app navigation work fine. But as soon as I publish my app on a webserver and try to got to a url that points to a rout in my app the routes aren't loaded and the app starts at the homepage.

For example:

Link I click from outside: https://flutter-project.com/#/contacts/ID6Nx2wTxgFcNW3gvMb2

Location the app opens in the browser: https://flutter-project.com/#/

**Is there a way to make this possible so that users can share links to other people and they can open them?**

Currenty the only way to open links is to open the webapp and then paste the link in the browserwindow where the app already was started but that is not the behaviour I expect from a webapp. I want to click the link and be right where it points at.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.

This is my web site: patrickferreira.com.br

It has these routes:

```
/calculadoracelular
/calculadorapc
/robotrader
```

if you try patrickferreira.com.br and click in one of the items in the fourth section it navigates to the routes as expected

But if you try to land directly on a subpage it throws a broken link error.

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/calculadoracelular':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductPage(work: tradeSizeCalculatorForMobile));
    case '/calculadorapc':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductPage(work: tradeSizeCalculatorForDesktop));
    case '/robotrader':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductPage(work: tradingBot));
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Portfólio Patrick Ferreira'));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Portfólio Patrick Ferreira',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => generateRoute(settings),
      initialRoute: '/#',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Portfólio Patrick Ferreira'),
        '/calculadorapc': (context) => ProductPage(work: tradeSizeCalculatorForDesktop),
        '/calculadoracelular': (context) => ProductPage(work: tradeSizeCalculatorForMobile),
        '/robotrader': (context) => ProductPage(work: tradingBot),
      },
    );
  }
}
```